# Where is the file of LOGIN model in Laravel 8, Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I need to edit the login model in laravel 8 and Jetstream-Livewire. My question is where is the file of Login Model can be located in Larvel 8, Jetstream-Livewire.

Comment: Never heard of a `Login` model out-of-the-box in Laravel, but there is a `User` model that extends the `Authenticatable` class, and it's probably the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modify the Login view**

> Go to `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php` and modify to this.

If you are using the Livewire stack, you should first publish the Livewire stack's Blade components:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

Next, you should customize the Models located in the

```
resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/dialog-modal.blade.php
```

> Note: No models available for login in jetstream as default. But
> jestream has dialog model and confirmation models. Using that you can
> create your own registration and login models.